# How to filter out non-numeric characters except ones matching a specific pattern in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have an array containing strings that represent numbers. The only two valid types of elements in the array are:

1. All-numeric strings (Eg: "123","123344")
2. Strings that match a specific pattern of xxx-xxxxx where all x are numbers (Eg:"123-12345", "233-30000").

This pattern can be added to more values in the future ie xx-xxxxx and x-xx-xxx where all x are still numbers:

I have the below code which solves 1 but not 2 :

```
const arr = ["ab's-test#s", "ab-c", "124", "123-12345"];
var arr2 = arr.filter(function(el) {
    return el.length && el==+el && el.match(new RegExp("^\\d{3}(-\\d{5})?$"));
});
console.log(arr2)
```

This prints out `["124"]`
However - I want it to print out `["124","123-12345"]`

Is there a way I can allow numbers and numeric patterns as a part of the same filter function? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The second set of `&&` should be `||`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional OR with regex to test your string is either number or number with pattern `xxx-xxxxx`.

```js
const arr = ["ab's-test#s", "ab-c", "124", "123-12345"],
      arr2 = arr.filter((str) => /^\d{3}-\d{5}$/.test(str) || /^\d+$/.test(str));
console.log(arr2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a single pattern placing the or `|` in the regex itself, using a non capture group `(?:....)` to match either of the alternatives between the anchors to assert the start and the end of the string:

The updated pattern will become:

```
^(?:\d{3}-\d{5}|\d+)$
```

```js
const arr = ["ab's-test#s", "ab-c", "124", "123-12345"];
const arr2 = arr.filter(str => /^(?:\d{3}-\d{5}|\d+)$/.test(str));

console.log(arr2)
```

Comment: For clarity sake you could change the non-capture group into a normal capture group. `/^(\d{3}-\d{5}|\d+)$/` Which makes the regex arguably better understandable for those who don't know much about regex.

Comment: @3limin4t0r You could do that indeed, it will give the same result. I usually don't use a capture group if the regex engine does not have to remember the group value.